# array sin numeros repetidos

Tags: java, método

Mi programa consiste en lo siguiente:

Generamos un array de 10 posiciones con números aleatorios de el 1 al 20,después con un método que se llama repetido comprobamos que los números que se han ido generando no están en el array,en caso de que estén on se meten y en caso contrario no se meten

Este es el codigo:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pruebaexamen {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Random rant = new Random();
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

    // crear un array de numeros aleatoros mas pequeños que el 20 y luego en
    // otro array mostrar los numeros mas pequeños que el 20 que no se hayan
    // generado en el array

    int[] array = new int[10];
    int numero = 0;
    // lo generamos
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        numero = rant.nextInt(20 - 0);
        if (repetido(array, numero) == false) {
            array[i] = numero;
        }
    }
    // comprovamos que no haya ningun numero repetidos

    // lo mostramos
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
}

public static boolean repetido(int[] array, int valor) {
    boolean repetido = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == valor) {// si el valor generado aleatoriamente esta
                                // dentro del array le marcamos como true y
                                // por lo tanto no lo metera en el array
            repetido = true;
        } else if (array[i] != valor) {

            repetido = false;
        }
    }
    return repetido;
}

}
```

La situación es la siguiente:
Aún habiendo hecho esto me sigue creando los números con algunas repeticiones,en qué he fallado? hay alguna otra manera de hacerlo o mejorarlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El error esta en tu condicional en el método `repetido`

Compruebas que en la interación actual el elemento exista, si existe cambias el booleano a `true` y si no existe lo pones a `false` y pasas al siguiente elemento del array. Si encuentras el valor en la 3ª posicion de 5 por ejemplo vas a poner el booleano a `true`, pero en la iteración 4 volverás a ponerlo a `false` y ahí reside el error.

Para solucionar esto bastaría con eliminar el `else` del método de la siguiente manera:

```
public static boolean repetido(int[] array, int valor) {
boolean repetido = false;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length && !repetido; i++) {
    if (array[i] == valor) {// si el valor generado aleatoriamente esta
                            // dentro del array le marcamos como true y
                            // por lo tanto no lo metera en el array
                            // al poner en la condicion del bucle que 
                            // repetido sea false, cuando lo ponemos a true
                            // salimos y evitamos iteraciones inecesarias
        repetido = true;
    }
}
   return repetido;
}
```

ya que por defecto repetido es false a menos que en alguna interacción encuentres el dato dentro del array, que repetido sería true.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias David de verdad,una pregunta es cierto qeu también podria hacerlo empleando un array de booleans? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: no tiene sentido usar un array de booleanos para lo que quieres hacer, yo utilizaría un while cuando llames al método que comprueba si el número esta repetido o no y siempre que de false vuelves a generar el numero aleatorio y vuelves a comprobar si existe, así siempre te generaría un array de 10 números del 1 al 20 aleatorios y que no se repitan.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes resolverlo muchísimo más fácilmente mediante el uso de streams de Java 8:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Random rant = new Random();
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

    // crear un array de números aleatorios mas pequeños que el 20 y luego en
    // otro array mostrar los números mas pequeños que el 20 que no se hayan
    // generado en el array

    int[] array = new int[10];
    int numero = 0;
    // lo generamos
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = rant.nextInt(20 - 0);
    }
    Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
    // comprobamos que no haya ningún numero repetidos
    System.out.println("Sin repetidos:");
    Arrays.stream(array).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu error está claro.
Cuando encuentra un valor repetido, pasa repetido a true, pero luego consulta el siguiente valor y si no coincide lo vuelve a pasar a false, ahí está tu error.

Para solucionarlo, cuando encuentre un repetido, teines que devolver true y no seguir mirando el resto de posiciones del array.

El código quedaría así:

```
public static boolean repetido(int[] array, int valor) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == valor) {
            return true; //Si está repetido devolvemos true
        }
    }
    return false; //Si ha acabado el bucle quiere decir que no había valores repetidos
                  //así que podemos devolver directamente false
}
```